# Is my Sales growth dependent on Commissions/Discounts and how do I analyze this in R?

Tags: r, regression, modeling

We are capturing sales data by time series (Month by month). Some of the items have commissions and some have discounts and others have both commissions and discounts. Is it commissions or discounts or commissions + discounts that have impact on my sales growth? Or is it that my sales are growing because of those commissions or discounts or discounts+commissions? Can you suggest me the best model to solve my use case? I am thinking about multiple regression. But I want to double check with experts like you.

Sample Data set: (5 variables)

```
Year-Month -Product -Sales  -Commission -Discounts
2013-01 Milk    300 No  Yes
2013-02 Milk    400 No  Yes
2013-03 Milk    200 No  Yes
2013-04 Milk    150 No  Yes
2013-05 Milk    500 No  Yes
2013-01 Bread   800 Yes No
2013-02 Bread   879 Yes No
2013-03 Bread   790 Yes No
2013-04 Bread   459 Yes No
2013-05 Bread   600 Yes No
2013-01 Cheese  400 Yes Yes
2013-02 Cheese  350 Yes Yes
2013-03 Cheese  600 Yes Yes
2013-04 Cheese  590 Yes Yes
2013-05 Cheese  720 Yes Yes
```

Comment: Unless commissions and discounts are varied over time for a product, you have no way to attribute growth in sales to either of them.  And when commissions and discounts vary, you ought to contemplate the reasons why they are changed--because those reasons might not be independent of the sales themselves.  Addressing these possibilities may be more important than the choice of a model.

Comment: @Whuber Thanks for your feedback. Commissions and Discounts are vary overtime for a product. Do you think I have to use real commissions/Discounts values in dollars or Zero dollars instead of Yes or NO? Is it Multiple regression is good model for this?